# Recover deleted database by mistake

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hello I use odoo 8 with postgresql 9.3 by mistake I deleted my official database, with Recover mylfiles I was able to retrieve the old data folder containing my database, so I replace the new folder by the older all works well but I still do not see my official base, thanks for your help

Comment: You'll probably need to restore from a backup. File recovery tools are unlikely to get a consistent view of the database at a particular point in the past. For example the `pg_database` shared catalog won't be wound back in time to before you dropped the DB. If it's really critical you can look at professional support to try to help you with data recovery, but expect to pay accordingly. See https://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/

Comment: If you have already recovered the old data directory, and just having trouble seeing the base directory, then just reinstall the old version of postgres from scratch and replace the data directory with old directory. Make sure to keep all install path same as before deletion. This should solve the issue. If there is still some problem, you need to check the consistency of recovered data.

Comment: Ok thank you , i will try this solution, and i will be back later

Comment: Hi @user3378908, did this solution work for you ? I have the same problem. Except my oddoo installation is hosted . Can I access to that directory?